# How to call a web service from Android Studio project

Tags: java, android-studio

I am new to Android and Java so excuse my lack of knowledge. I am trying to get a response to a web service I wrote in .NET.

It is a simple service. Pass userid and passwd and it returns the user last name if found or NO if not found. I have a VB 2017 program that is working as expected but trying to also have the same results in an Android environment.

Here are my imports:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.SocketException;
import org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.SoapFault;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.PropertyInfo;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapPrimitive;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException;
```

On a button click I have the following.

```
{
  String userID = "Tom";
  String pwd = "&yhe$43*";

  userid = new PropertyInfo();
  password = new PropertyInfo();

  SoapObject request = new SoapObject("http://tempuri.org/", "WebService1");

  SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
  envelope.dotNet = true;
  envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
  HttpTransportSE httpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

  userid.setName("userID");
  userid.setValue(userID);
  userid.setType(String.class);
  password.setName("password");
  password.setValue("Yo");
  password.setType(String.class);

  request.addProperty(userid);
  request.addProperty(password);
  try {
    httpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
    SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();
    String resp = response.toString();
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, (CharSequence) resp, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  } catch (Exception e) {
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, (CharSequence) e, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  }
}
```

Error is happening on this line:

```
httpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
```

Looks like it is getting a

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
```

Is there something obviously wrong here?

Here is data Logcat:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:402)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6294)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24770)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:397)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6294) 
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24770) 
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException cannot be cast to java.lang.CharSequence
    at com.example.myapplication.MainActivity.getName(MainActivity.java:71)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:397) 
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6294) 
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24770) 
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

Comment: Post full error log, you can find it in logcat

Comment: added it to my original question

Comment: I have added an answer, please check and let me know :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this line, I would assume:

```
       Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, (CharSequence) e, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

You're casting e (of type "Exception") to a CharSequence, which is obviously illegal, since a class can't inherit from both Exception and CharSequence.

Try using "e.getMessage()" instead of "(CharSequence) e". That won't fix the actual cause of the exception but at least you will be able to see what the actual exception is.

Comment: Thanks. Got past the original issue and now getting HTTP request failed HTTP status: 400

Comment: 400 is a "Bad Request": https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/400 - meaning that your request is not formed as the server expects it. You can use tools like TCP Monitor to see what you are actually sending to the server, but without actually knowing the server's API, it's hard to further diagnose the cause.

Answer (score 0):

```
android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
```

From the error log you posted, I can see that you are doing a Network task in the android main thread.

this exception comes when you do Network operation on the main thread. please schedule this task in a background thread.

For your reference, I have included a link that describes how to solve this
[How to fix 'android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException'?](http://How%20to%20fix%20'android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException'?)

And also change this

```
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, (CharSequence) e, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

to

```
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

finally, make sure you have added Internet permission in the manifest file.

Happy coding!!